# Generalized Quadratic Loss Function with Deep Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks

Let

\begin{equation}
  D_{i,j} = e^{- \gamma_D ||\vec{x_i} - \vec{x_j}  ||^2}
\end{equation}

where $\vec{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $d$ the dimension of the feature input space, $\gamma_D$ is an hyper-parmeter, and $\vec{o}$ the binary cross entropy standard loss for binary classification.

Is PyTorch (autograd for automatic differentiation) able to determine the gradient of the loss

\begin{equation}
\vec{o}' D \vec{o}
\end{equation}

for back-propagation?